# How does the probabilty for universal hashing work out?

Tags: universal-hash

Hey for universal hashing we say the following:

**Definition:**
A randomized algorithm $H$ for constructing hash functions $h\colon U \to \{1,\ldots,M\}$
is **universal** if for all $x \neq y$ in $U$, we have
$\Pr_{h\gets H} [h(x) = h(y)] \leq 1/M$

I actually just can´t understand how the probability can be $1/M$ in any case. I alway try to think about any random function mod M as example and compare it with rolling a dice, but with a dice we have for every instance a probabilty of 1/6 as we have 1/M for mod M. But when I roll a dice two times after I have at least $\frac{1}{6}^2$ but saying we have binomial probabilty it looks even worse thinking that the dice would be thrown y times.

Can you help me understand how 1/m could be reached within this context?

Comment: That is a definition to achieve. Did you look at the [Wegman-Carter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing)

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4y3EW_q9lfw) on the subject might clear things up.

Comment: Actually it's the follow up [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBW0OW5fR_A) that answers your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actualy chance of 2 dice throws to have the same value is 1\6, not 1\36. And definition also compares 2 values.

What you are asking is called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem and it is still present even with universal hashing. Or dice throws. If more than 2 are compared.

Comment: Thank you! This [link](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/math/how-to-solve-the-famous-birthday-problem) made it even more clear regarding birthday problem and rolling a dice.